# Datagridview valuetype property not changing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, double, value-type

I have some code to convert the datatypes of some of the columns of a datagridview into a double, as they should be displaying as currency in my grid view.
However when I run the code, the values are still displayed as a normal decimal. Am I using the wrong code to do what I want, or can this simply not be done? I appreciate any help you can give me.
Here is my code:

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count -1
    InventoryDataGridView.ColumnCount = ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count
    InventoryDataGridView.Columns(1).ValueType = GetType(Date) 'this type changes
    InventoryDataGridView.Columns(2).ValueType = GetType(Double) 'this line and the line below do not occur in the grid view
    InventoryDataGridView.Columns(4).ValueType = GetType(Double)
    InventoryDataGridView.Columns(i).Name = InventoryColumns(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event to show your currency:

```
Private Sub InventoryDataGridView_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles InventoryDataGridView.CellFormatting
  If (e.ColumnIndex = 2) Then
    e.Value = String.Format("{0:$0.00}", e.Value)
    e.FormattingApplied = True
  End If
End Sub
```